# Protractor 3.1.1 (adding Angular debug logging flag to the Protractor run)

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Recently upgraded to Protractor 3.1.1 and testing the [debug feature](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/148f020bf4bbd71e17326581a2f7ed6f4ff55832)

I understand that the debug flag added in the `protractor.js` helps to run the tests for applications with `.debugInfoEnabled(false);`

But my test doesn't run right out of the box, I hack it by using `browser.executeScript('window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO!"');` in order to get it running.

But wasn't this the whole point of upgrading to Protractor 3.1.1 so you don't have to do this?!

Any suggestions?